# Truncate file at the end with PHP

Tags: php

I have a log file that I would like to truncate after it has been read by PHP. My code currently looks like this:

```
$fp = fopen($file, "r+");
ftruncate($fp, 125000);
fclose($fp);
```

However, this truncates the file by keeping the *first* 1Mb. However, I would like to keep the *last* 1Mb of the file; logs lines are appended so I would like to keep the most recent entries, rather than the oldest (the post-truncate file would always be the same with this code).

Comment: This is what [`ftruncate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php) does. If you want to keep the tail of the file you have to write your own code that copies the desired part into a new file then replaces the old file with the new one.

Comment: If another process has the log file open for writing, and they didn't use "append" mode, they won't adjust to the truncated position. Log file rotation is usually done by renaming the file and sending a signal to the logger telling them to start a new file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `ftruncate` function to perform this process, since it only accept the final truncation size as argument and the truncation is performed starting from the beginning. Give this a try:

```
// open the file for reading only
$fp = fopen($file,'r');
// place the pointer at END - 125000
fseek($fp,-125000,SEEK_END);
// read data from (END - 125000) to END
$data = fgets($fp,125000);
// close the file handle
fclose($fp);

// overwrite the file content with data
file_put_contents($file,$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, simple enough and does the trick :)

```
$logsToKeep = file_get_contents($file, NULL, NULL, -125000, 125000);
file_put_contents($file,$logsToKeep);
```

edit: if running version prior to v7.1 (anywhere from php5), you can use

```
$offset=filesize($file)-125000;
if($offset>0){
    $logsToKeep = file_get_contents($file, NULL, NULL, $offset, 125000);
    file_put_contents($file,$logsToKeep);
}
```

but this does reduce efficiency. the answer being efficiency driven. To quote php doc , "file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance." So a clean call to a negative offset remains the best way to get the last N bytes of a file.

Comment: Negative offset isn't available until PHP 7.1.0.